# Constraint Table in Postgresql Empty

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am currently working on a set of queries to pull data from a SQL table and then loop to pull any entries from other tables that are referenced in the first table through foreign keys.

> aka if Table A column A can only have values that appear in Table B's primary key, I want to pull all rows of Table B referenced in my extract from Table A.

To do this in the past, I would have written a query that looks at `information_schema.table_constraints` and matched it against the key columns; Something like the suggested query in [this article](https://dataedo.com/kb/query/postgresql/list-foreign-keys). However, when I pull the information from the `table_constraints` table in my current database, I get back an empty response; I get the table headers, but no rows. This is despite the fact that I know that there are many constraints, particularly foreign-key constraints, in the Postgresql database that I am using. The query giving me the empty response is as simple as possible, shown below:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.table_constraints
```

Is there somewhere else that I should be referencing to get the foreign key constraint information? How else can I find the foreign key constraints on a table?

EDIT: I am having a touch more luck finding things through `pg_catalog`; The data at least seems to exist in there. However, it is all abstracted as numerical IDs, and I am having a little trouble linking enough together to get to the actual column names and other key data.

Comment: Are you logged in as the right user? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/infoschema-table-constraints.html You could do a select count(*) to see if it has zero rows?

Comment: I tried a `SELECT COUNT(*)...` just then and got 0 as the return

Comment: That query works fine here.  Permissions/login issue?

Comment: Must have been permissions. Ended up solving it by copying the schema of the database, spinning up a new one with that schema, then querying that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `information_schema` views you can only see objects for which you have permissions.

You are planning to do a join, not lots of little queries by primary key, right?

Comment: Yeah, a join; Want to pull all of the parent rows from all tables that a table has foreign key references to